# PHP: Express Number in Words

Tags: php, numbers

Is there a function that will express any given number in words?

For example:

If a number is `1432`, then this function will return "One thousand four hundred and thirty two".

Answer (score 191):

Use the [NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) that are in php ;)

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(1432);
```

That would output "one thousand four hundred thirty-two"

Comment: It's part of the PECL intl extension

Comment: If you want a more verbose output use 

`$f->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%spellout-numbering-verbose");` which will output `one thousand four hundred and thirty-two`

Comment: How does one get the PECL intl extension? Ubuntu PHP 7.2 server. Also is this still OK? It's maintenance stopped in 2013 with version 3.0.0 @yitznewton

Comment: Sorry, I switched companies and stopped using PHP right after I posted that comment, so I'm afraid I don't know anything about the current ecosystem

Comment: This "$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);" 
is not working for me, any tips to make this work? I'm using MS Edge for this.

Comment: It also handles decimals, e.g. 12.34 -> twelve point three four.

Comment: This solution not worked for me. getting error `NumberFormatter class not found`. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 45):

You can do this in many ways I am mentioning here two ways by using [The NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) as mentioned in [Martindilling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500088/php-express-number-in-words/26631086#26631086) answer (if you have php version 5.3.0 or higher and also PECL extension 1.0.0 or higher) or by using the following custom function.

```
function convertNumberToWord($num = false)
{
    $num = str_replace(array(',', ' '), '' , trim($num));
    if(! $num) {
        return false;
    }
    $num = (int) $num;
    $words = array();
    $list1 = array('', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven',
        'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
    );
    $list2 = array('', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety', 'hundred');
    $list3 = array('', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion', 'quintillion', 'sextillion', 'septillion',
        'octillion', 'nonillion', 'decillion', 'undecillion', 'duodecillion', 'tredecillion', 'quattuordecillion',
        'quindecillion', 'sexdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion'
    );
    $num_length = strlen($num);
    $levels = (int) (($num_length + 2) / 3);
    $max_length = $levels * 3;
    $num = substr('00' . $num, -$max_length);
    $num_levels = str_split($num, 3);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($num_levels); $i++) {
        $levels--;
        $hundreds = (int) ($num_levels[$i] / 100);
        $hundreds = ($hundreds ? ' ' . $list1[$hundreds] . ' hundred' . ' ' : '');
        $tens = (int) ($num_levels[$i] % 100);
        $singles = '';
        if ( $tens < 20 ) {
            $tens = ($tens ? ' ' . $list1[$tens] . ' ' : '' );
        } else {
            $tens = (int)($tens / 10);
            $tens = ' ' . $list2[$tens] . ' ';
            $singles = (int) ($num_levels[$i] % 10);
            $singles = ' ' . $list1[$singles] . ' ';
        }
        $words[] = $hundreds . $tens . $singles . ( ( $levels && ( int ) ( $num_levels[$i] ) ) ? ' ' . $list3[$levels] . ' ' : '' );
    } //end for loop
    $commas = count($words);
    if ($commas > 1) {
        $commas = $commas - 1;
    }
    return implode(' ', $words);
}
```

Comment: Nice function, looks ok so far - note that `hundred` is always `hundred` and will not follow with an `s`

Comment: If it helps you you should vote up, but If you vote down please explain the reason! Thanks

Comment: Nice function. But I think you should fix the "hundreds" thing. @Onimusha has also pointed this out.

Comment: thanks @StephenAdelakun for reminder but its just a variable the actual string used is hundred.

Comment: it doesn't show the point part ..How do you concat that?

Comment: `return implode(' ', $words);` gave me a bunch of weird white space between and around words. This won't be noticeable if the strings are output to html of course, but for the OCD crowd you can use a regex and trim() to eliminate it. Replace that line with `return trim(preg_replace('~[\\s]+~', ' ', implode(' ', $words)));`

Comment: When dealing large numbers larger dan int, use floor. `$num = floor($num);`. Wrong output when number is larger than 2billion

Comment: I am looking solution like `BRUNEI DOLLARS THIRTY-FIVE THOUSAND SIX HUNDERED AND FORTY-TWO for 35,642.00`. any suggestion, please share

Answer (score 14):

Yes, http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

However this is pretty dirty example. Please use [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) from intl (this will work from PHP 5.3)

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("in", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(123456);
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same link. It's in the first page of google results even.

Comment: right now it displays '259833' as :-two hundred and fifty-nine thousand, eight hundred and thirty-three. I would like it to displayed as "Two lakhs fifty nine thousand eight hundred thirty three".

Comment: Um, is that wrong?

Comment: no - How do I display it in Indian number format?

Comment: change `100 => 'hundred'` to `100 => 'lakhs'`

Comment: @LeysamRosario
I think he will gonna have to do more than that. as in indian term there is hundred term for hundered, but when it comes to 0.1 Million , it is said to be 1 lakh, and 1 Million = Ten Lakh and 10 Million = One Carore.

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov The link is dead, hence why I removed it. Also, by adding the broken link back in, you're putting yourself back in the crosshairs of [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu)

Answer (score 11):

In case of using Yii2 you can do this as simple as the following:

```
$sum = 100500;
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asSpellout($sum);
```

This prints spelled out `$sum` in your app's language.

Docs [reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asSpellout()-detail)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know yii2 had something this handy