# Convert numeric string into string

Tags: php

Basically I have the following string:

```
1,254.40
```

And I have to convert it into the following thing:

```
one * two * five * four * usd * four * zero * cents
```

How can I do that? So far I've written something like this:

```
public function priceToString($price)
{
    $output = "";

    $chars = str_split($price);

    foreach($chars as $char)
    {
        if(is_numeric($char))
        {
            $output .= (string)$char . " *";
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

But it doesn't work because it displays simply integers...How can I solve this?

Comment: There are cetains APIs available to do this (http://bloople.net/num2text/) You may find this post helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500088/php-express-number-in-words

Comment: You have to write code to convert each number into the text equivalent (and the same with the usd and cents).

Comment: you should create a mapping array for each number

Answer (score 1):

(Didnt check for validity, but something along these lines:

```
$numericText = array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine');

$price = '1,254.40';
$chars = str_split($price);
foreach($chars as $char) {
    if(is_numeric($char)) {
        $output .= $numericText[(int)$char] . " *";
    } elseif($char == '.') {
        $output .= 'usd *';
    }
}
$output .= ' cents';
```