# Woocommerce: How-to show ‘Order Total’ amount in Words

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my Woocommerce website, I need to display **`Total Order Amount` in words**, which will be shown on Checkout Page, Cheque Payment & on Invoice.

Example: **`1590.00 (One thousand five hundred & ninety only)`**

How can we achieve this?
TIA

Comment: Maybe see the [`woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try number formatter class as mentioned in these threads [a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631086/6877482) and [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277569/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-in-php)

Use the filter "woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html".

```
function custom_woocommerce_order_amount_total( $order_total ) { 
$number_total = WC()->cart->get_total();
// number formatting goes here;
// using number formatter class 
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$total_in_words = $f->format($number_total); // Total in words
$order_total =   $total_in_words;      
return $order_total; 
    }; 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'custom_woocommerce_order_amount_total' );
```

You can also try the other hooks like woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total

Comment: Perfect. This worked. Thank you Here is the final code I used for Invoice & cheque payments. `$number_total = $this->order->get_total();
// number formatting goes here;
// using number formatter class 
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$total_in_words = $f->format($number_total); // Total in words
$order_total =   $total_in_words; 
echo $order_total;`

Comment: Thanks for revert back with working code. I will use this snippet too.